# Magento 1.9 can't add item to cart

Tags: cart, addtocart

I use Magento 1.9 and now i have problem with adding item to cart, when i press button Add to cart, just refresh page and in cart nothing, i added in Session Cookie Management -> Cookie Lifetime = 86400, but nothing, early all working good with my site. Can you help solve problem?

Comment: Sounds like the `formkey` block isn't being rendered or the form key isn't being sent.  The form key is a protection for your site and form posts without it will not accept the request and redirect you.

Comment: ok, where i can add this points? in addtocart.phtm?

Comment: Yes.  Typically it's the line directly following the `<form>` tag in most other Magento forms.

Comment: i added <?php $formKey = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey();?> and in <form> added hidden input: <input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo $formKey; ?>" /> - but products can not add to cart

Comment: The `formkey` is a block that you should be able to just do `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('formkey'); ?>` to get the full input.

Comment: <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('formkey'); ?> add before tag <form> ?

Comment: No, it needs to be added somewhere within the `<form>` tag as it needs to be sent with the data to add to the cart.

Comment: no, not working

Comment: Do you have any errors in any of your logs (any: Magento and PHP and webserver)?

Comment: You have changed magento server or webstie name ?

Comment: no, all data is same

Comment: Sorry, it's not `getChildHtml` it's `getBlockHtml`.  See if that works.

Comment: <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?> in <form> tag not working